# Getting the diskutil command to work in OSX Mavericks Single User mode

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, disk-utility

I'm currently writing some single user mode maintenance scripts. My current goal is to be able to perform permission repairs and disk formatting using the diskutil command in Single User Mode. Performing this task in previous versions of OS X was a simple matter of mounting the root partition and launching the following launch daemons:

`com.apple.diskmanagementd`

`com.apple.diskarbitrationd`

After that, I only needed to run the following command to successfully repair permissions:

`diskutil repairpermissions /`

In Mavericks, however, this command no longer works and I can't figure out why. Running the diskutil command (even with no parameters) returns a simple and unhelpful message:

`Killed: 9`

I can't figure out what's going on here. In addition to the disk arbitration daemons that diskutil requires, my maintenance script also loads the following daemons:

`com.apple.notifyd`

`com.apple.syslogd`

`com.apple.configd`

`com.apple.kuncd`

`com.apple.kextd`

`com.apple.KernelEventAgent`

`com.apple.distnoted.xpc.daemon`

`com.apple.aslmanager`

`com.apple.opendirectoryd`

`com.apple.coreservicesd`

`com.apple.securityd`

`com.apple.fseventsd`

`com.apple.cfprefsd.xpc.daemon`

I get the same response whether I load all of the above daemons or just the two that were previously required for diskutil to operate. If I choose to boot from single user mode (by loading the entire contents of /System/Library/LaunchDaemons) I can use diskutil after the computer has finished its boot process.

Can someone more knowledgeable about the inner workings of the Mac OS possibly determine what's missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what's causing the problem, but it doesn't seem to be a missing daemon -- I tried loading everything in `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons` except `com.apple.WindowServer.plist`, and it still failed the same way. It even fails just running `diskutil`, which normally just prints a usage summary. Also, "Killed: 9" suggests it isn't crashing itself, but something else (`launchd`?) is killing it.

Anyway, there is a bit of good news: `diskutil repairpermissions` is really just a front end for the `repair_packages` program, and that seems to run fine in single-user mode (even with no daemons at all loaded):

```
/usr/libexec/repair_packages --repair --standard-pkgs
```

Formatting disks will probably be more difficult. You may have to look at using `gpt`, `newfs_hfs`, and the like.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a bunch. It looks like it's been `repair_packages` since 10.6.

Comment: By the way, do you have any idea how I would go about checking the SMART status from single user mode? The old way of doing this is `diskutil info disk0 | grep SMART`, but this no longer works.

Comment: No idea on SMART, sorry. That may be one diskutil does itself.

Answer (score -1):

el capitan is now protecting permissions, even with your /usr/libexec/repair_packages --repair --standard-pkgs (thanks for it)  it's not more possible to repair permissions - the file systems to repair are read only - any hint ?
Best regards and thanks
Martin

Comment: I found something - perhaps working with disable system protection

Comment: You can easily disable SIP with `csrutil disable` in Recovery mode