# Cant boot MacBook Pro - HDD File System is Read-Only

Tags: macos, hard-drive, macbook-pro, disk-utility

I have a big problem - I think. The problem seems to be that my HDD is Read-Only so I can't boot and can not erase the HDD to reinstall the system.

But here is the whole story:

I bought a used MacBook Pro 13" from Mid 2009. It was used by a friend and he used it until yesterday without any problems. I bought it and he erased the system and then I configurated the system for my preferences. I booted and everything worked fine. But then this happened:

1. I changed the System-Language in `System Preferences -> Language` to German and then restarted.
2. When restarting the Apple Logo appears and a loading Bar is bottom of this. The Bar took about 3 minutes to load - and then the MacBook shut down. That's it. I tried it about 5 times - everytime the same.
3. I googled and used `CMD + V` at the start to see what's happening and I saw that the problem is that the system tries to repair the "volume" - my HDD. After the third repeat the system shuts down.
4. So I tried the following steps to solve this:
5. `CMD + R` when restarting to go to `DiskUtil`. In this I tried to scan the HDD. It returns that it should be repaired. I clicked repair and I got the message that `DiskUtils` can not repair the HDD. Then I clicked on the HDD and saw that it doesnt seems to be mounted... I tried to mounted but: "Can not mount this - try to repair and try again..." - but this still doenst work. So I was going on ...
6. `CMD + S` to get into the console before starting the system. There I tried this: `diskutil list`. This returned: "`Killed 9`". Not more and not less. So I googled it:
7. I found this page: [http://superuser.com/questions/698310/getting-the-diskutil-command-to-work-in-osx-mavericks-single-user-mode`  So I tried the accepted comment...]
8. and typed this into the console: `/usr/libexec/repair_packages --repair --standard-pkgs` This command returned this:

   Group differs on "Library/Java", should be 0, group is 80.

   Permissions differ on "Library/Java", should be drwxr-xr-x, they are drwxrwxr-x.

   Unable to set owner & group on "Library/Java", Error 30: Read-Only file system

   Unable to set Permissions on "Library/Java". Error 30: Read-only file system

Okay - that's it. This is all information I have and I realy dont know how to solve this ... any idea ? :/

Information:
The OS seems to be OSX.

Comment: Have you tried going into Single-User mode (CMD + S) and running fsck -fy in order to run a check on the hard-disk to make sure that it indeed is not dying on you? Most of the time you see a loading bar at boot, this means the hard-disk is failing

Comment: Yes fsck -fy I also tried and its the same like CMD + V. Its trieing to repeair 3 times and after 3 times the script stops and I can type again another command. It tells me "Incorrect number of thread records (4, 288)

Answer (score 1):

I've encounter this problem way too many times.  Usually it means that the hard drive is logically too messed up to be repaired.  I usually hook it up to a Mac, dump the home directory, and then reformat the hard drive and copy the home directory back.  A few times, it's actually been a true hardware failure, but usually, it's just logical.

I've had some corruption so bad that Mac OS X itself can't recover anything off the hard drive, and in that case, I use a Linux Distribution (in my case, OpenSUSE) to yank the data.  OpenSUSE can write to HFS+ partitions as long as you disable journaling on them before hand.

I usually use this command, in the case of both Mac and Linux, to copy data off.  As long as you are copying to a POSIX filesystem, it'll keep the permissions.

$ sudo rsync -av --progress /run/media/linux/Macintosh\ HD/USERNAME /run/media/linux/EXTERNALHD/USERNAME

Comment: At home I have a Home PC with Linux (Ubuntu) on it. So it is possible to clean up the hDD with Linux ( I know how to) and then to reuse it for my Mac ? Or when doing this the error will occure again and again and again ... so its better to buy a new HDD ?

Comment: What I would do, is load up Linux via a Live CD and run an extended SMART test on the hard drive.  I find that _much_ more reliable than relying on Mac OS X itself.

As long as the hard drive is formatted for HFS+, you should be fine.